# Question on proving : Outer measure is countably subadditive

Tags: real-analysis

Let {$E_k$}$_{k=1} ^\infty $ be any countable collection of sets.

We want to show:

$m^{*}\left( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_k \right) \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} m^{*}(E_k)$

In the proving progress, let $\epsilon$ $>0$ . For each natural number $k$, there is a countable collection {$I_{k,i}$}$_{k=1} ^\infty$ of open, bounded intervals for which

$E_k$ $\subset$ $\cup_{i=1} ^\infty I_{k,i}$ and $\sum_{i=1} ^\infty l(I_{k,i})$ $<$ $m^* (E_k)$ $+ \frac{\epsilon}{2^k}$ . ($l$ represents length.)

Then, $m^*(\cup_{k=1}^\infty E_k)$ $\le$ $\sum_{k=1}^\infty[\sum_{i=1} ^\infty l(I_{k,i})]$ $<$ $\sum _{k=1} ^\infty (m^*(E_k)$ + $\frac{\epsilon}{2^k}$) =[$\sum _{k=1} ^\infty m^*(E_k)$]+$\epsilon$ .

But I feel like it proved : $m^{*}\left( \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} E_k \right) \lt \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} m^{*}(E_k)$ , I mean, I think equality was not proved.

since $m^*(\cup_{k=1}^\infty E_k)$ $<$ $\sum _{k=1} ^\infty [m^*(E_k)$ + $\frac{\epsilon}{2^k}$].

Is it really well-proved?

Comment: If $a < b + \epsilon$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, then the most you can conclude is that $a \leq b$. Not $a<b$.

Comment: @littleO  What "the most" means?

Comment: Maybe it would have been more clear if I had just said, "then you can conclude that $a \leq b$, but you can't conclude that $a < b$."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For proving $a \leq b$, it is a routine to check that for any $\varepsilon >0$, $a < b + \varepsilon$. These 2 statements are equivalent. If $a \leq b$, it is obvious to get the latter statement. If the latter statement holds, but suppose we cannot get $a \leq b$, then there exist $\varepsilon_0$, such that $a > b+ \varepsilon_0$, contradictory to the condition. So this 2 statements are equal.